# How to resize a vector of vector of unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr

How to properly resize a vector of unique_ptr vectors in one line without gcc giving a compilation error regarding a deleted function?

```
vector<vector<unique_ptr<A> >> a;
a.resize(..... )
```

UPDATE:
This is the code that I used that works OK.

```
  int width, height;
  vector<vector<unique_ptr<A> >> a;
  a.resize(width);
  for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
          a.at(i).emplace_back(new A());
```

If possible, I would like to resize the sizes in one go just like resizing of vector of vectors;

```
vector<vector<int>> intObj;
intObj.resize(width, vector<int>(height, int()));
```

but I got this error whenever I tried to resize the above vectors using the following method;

```
a.resize(x, vector<unique_ptr<A>>(y, unique_ptr<A>()));

error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = A; _Dp = std::default_delete<A>]’
```

Thanks.

Comment: `vector<vector<...>>` is a code smell to me in this scenario. You should use a single vector that is `width*height` in size, not a vector of vectors. NOTE: If you make this change, a call to `a.resize(width*height)` will work.

Comment: Exactly what code did you try, and what error did you get?

Comment: @Simple I tend to disagree. `vector<vector<>>` is more scalable as the memory used to held data doesn't need to be continuous which might be necessary for a large amount of data. Also I have seen way to many wrong calculated offsets...

Comment: @Simple The one-argument version may well work.

Comment: BTW, `emplace_back(new A())` = leak. Don't do it; use `push_back(make_unique<A>())`

Comment: @T.C. right, I was just considering the overloads that took a count and a value. Realise I didn't word it very well.

Comment: @TC Thanks, I didn't know that. Also I updated the question with the gcc error output.

Comment: @user2924261 Perhaps you could just define a new overload that makes use of move?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `vector<unique_ptr<A>>` is a non-copyable type, because
`unique_ptr<A>` cannot be copied. `a.resize(x, vector<unique_ptr<A>>(y))` uses the copy constructor of the `vector<unique_ptr<A>>` and `a.resize(x, vector<unique_ptr<A>>(y, unique_ptr<A>()))` is even worse as it uses the copy constructor of both `unique_ptr<A>` and `vector<unique_ptr<A>>`.

Two solutions:

1. Use a single `vector<unique_ptr<A>>` that has size `x*y`. This means
   `a.resize(x*y)` will work as intended.
2. Or, you will need to use a loop over all of the sub vectors.

Example of loop:

```
a.resize(x);
for (auto& i : a) {
    i.resize(y);
}
```

EDIT: If you wanted the `unique_ptr<A>`s to point at default constructed `A`s and not `nullptr`, then you can use this code:

```
a.resize(x);
for (auto& i : a) {
    i.reserve(y);
    for (int j = 0; y != j; ++j) {
        i.push_back(std::make_unique<A>());
    }
}
```

You can't use a single `resize` call to do what you want if you maintain your current design.

EDIT 2: Here's a one liner for default constructing `As` if you go with solution 1:

```
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(a), x*y, []{ return std::make_unique<A>(); });
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still result in all `unique_ptr`s being initiliazed with `nullptr`?

Comment: @SimonKraemer that's what his original code for `a.resize(x, vector<unique_ptr<A>>(y, unique_ptr<A>()))` was trying to do. I see what he really wants is default constructed `A`s, so I'll edit in a bit.

Comment: @Simple Thanks. I guess I have to go with the second solution, otherwise other parts of the code will have to be changed as well. So I guess there's no way to resize a vector of vectors of non-copyable type since the resizing invokes copy constructor, unless I define a new overload that makes use of move?

Comment: @user2924261 I don't know what your overload that uses `move` would do, but note that my solution creates `unique_ptr`s and then moves them in to the vector. An alternative is to use some kind of `value_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr` (read up on it) that performs a deep copy when copied.

Comment: A thousand thanks for the information, that the operation would (in addition to the classes move constructor/ move =oprtator) require a vector<unique_ptr<A>> (move) constructor. That clarifies things a lot imho. Upvote also for the one-line solution (I forgot about the back_inserter...)

Answer (score -4):

std::unique_ptr is not copyable use std::shared_ptr for full container support.

Comment: ...and create a container of w*h pointers all to the same one object?